# PEReference error with XML external ENTITY DTD

Tags: xml, import, entity, external, doctype

I have this XML code declaring an external DTD ENTITY:

```
<!DOCTYPE customers [
 <!ENTITY % itemCodes SYSTEM "codes.dtd">
 %itemCodes;
]>
```

This is simply to call up some pre-written codes from *codes.dtd*:

```
<!ENTITY DCT5Z "Tapan Digital Camera 5 Mpx - zoom">
<!ENTITY SM128 "SmartMedia 128MB Card">
<!-- etc. -->
```

But I get this error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 53 at column 8: PEReference: %itemCodes; not found
```

Why would that be?

Answer (score 1):

*Why would that be?*

Because it can't find the `codes.dtd` file.  If you aren't using some sort of catalog based resolution mechanism, then the `codes.dtd` would have to be in the working directory of the program you're running.

But an error on line 53 seems odd.  That's too far into a file for a DTD.  What does line 53 look like?

**UPDATE**: On reconsideration, the problem may not be that `codes.dtd` couldn't be found, but that the XML parser being used doesn't process external entities.  (After all, it said that the PE reference itself, and not its referent, couldn't be found.)  This is a quite common limitation of non-validating parsers, but the error diagnostic could have been more helpful ("Sorry, external entity references are not supported".)

Comment: If what you're say is true, then why would the DTD file not be found within the same directory as the XML file? I have everything placed together and am simply trying to open the file in Chrome. Also, The reason line 53 shows up is because the DOCTYPE has some internal declarations that I excluded.

Comment: In that case, I may have misunderstood the error message. I'll add an update.

Comment: Isn't Chrome's XML support quite limited?  If you put the entire internal subset in another dtd file and just have `<!DOCTYPE customers SYSTEM "external.dtd">`, you may find out whether external entities are supported.

Comment: It seems to work fine on Firefox. However, Firefox can't seem to import the codes I saved in the DTD.